# Confusion with Expected Value

Tags: probability

I'm having some trouble with this question:

If I line up *n* boys and *m* girls, what is the expected number of times that a girl comes directly after a boy in the line?

I'm not really sure how to approach it- how can I model this situation?

Comment: Hint: how many ways are there to line everyone up, and in how many of them does a girl come directly after a boy?

Comment: @Vedvart1 I think there are (n + m)! ways to line everyone up, but I'm not sure how many ways there are to line a girl up after a boy. I'm also not sure how to translate this into an expected value for the number of times a girl comes after a boy

Comment: For the number of ways to line everyone up, you are close, but you need to account for the fact that we don't care *which* boy or girl is in a spot, just whether that person is a boy or a girl. Thus your number is overcounting a little: If the boys are James, Brad, and Ken, and the girls are Jenna and Veronica, then you are counting

*Ken, James, Veronica, Brad, Jenna* and 
*Brad, Ken, Jenna, James, Veronica*

as two different lineups. But both are BBGBG, so should be considered the same. How could you account for these repeats?

Comment: For expected value, what is the definition you are given of expected value?

Comment: @Vedvart1 (n + m)!/n!/m!

Comment: Yep! Now the second number - in how many of these does a girl come directly after a boy?

Comment: @Vedvart1 Expected value should be the sum of all valid values * their probabilities, but I'm not sure how to account for different numbers of girls coming after boys in the general case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131430/discussion-between-vedvart1-and-rebecca-deitch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me introduce you to indicator variables, these are a fantastic tool used in calculating expectations.

If I toss $10$ coins what is the expected number of heads? You should know this as $5$ but let me show you another method. Let $S$ be the random variable, number of heads. Let each $X_i$ be $1$ if the $i^{th}$ coin is heads and $0$ otherwise. It should then be clear that

$S = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10 } X_i$

Then taking expectation, and using its linearirty, we have that $\mathbb{E}[S] =  \mathbb{E}[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}X_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}\mathbb{P}[X_i=1] \cdot 1 + \mathbb{P}[X_i=0] \cdot 0 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}\mathbb{P}[X_i=1] =  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}\frac{1}{2} =5 $

Naturally, you are thinking " Okay funny man well done, I already knew how to do that! I want my problem solved. " Here is how we can use indicator variables in your case:

We have a total of $n+m$ spots in our line, of which all but the first could result in a girl in front of a boy.
Hence $n+m-1 $ potential chances for our desired event.

Let $X_i$ for $i =
2 , 3,\dots,n+m$ be the indicator of the $(i-1)^{th}$ person is a boy and the $i^{th}$ a girl. That is $1$ if we have $BG$ in spot $i-1, i$ and $0$ otherwise.  Let $S$ denote the total number of times we have a boy followed by a girl.

Hence the total number of times we have a boy followed by a girl is: 
$S = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n+m}X_i$

We are nearly done now, we just need to take advantage of the linearity of expectation. We see that as before $\mathbb{E}[S] = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n+m}\mathbb{E}[X_i]$

And so to finish this problem we simply need to find $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$

The $X_i$ are most definitely not independent, however we do not care as expectation is linear. However they are identically distributed! And so we only need to for example find $\mathbb{E}[X_2]$.

$\mathbb{E}[X_2] = \mathbb{P}[X_2 =1]\cdot 1 + \mathbb{P}[X_2 = 0]\cdot 0 = \mathbb{P}[X_2 =1]$

(this is true for all indicator variables, that is their expectation is simply the probability they are $1$)

$\mathbb{P}[X_2 = 1] = \frac{n}{n+m} \cdot \frac{m}{n+m-1}$ as we need a boy to be the first person in the line and then a girl to be second.

Hence $\mathbb{E}[S] = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n+m}\mathbb{E}[X_i] =\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n+m} \frac{n}{n+m} \cdot \frac{m}{n+m-1} = (n+m-1) \cdot \frac{n}{n+m} \cdot \frac{m}{n+m-1} = \frac{nm}{n+m} $

And we are done!

You could check this for the simple case $n=m=1$ and note that we either have $BG$ or $GB$ both we equally probability and so $\mathbb{E} = \frac{1}{2} $ in this case, which agrees with our formula $\frac{1\cdot 1}{1 +1 }$